# I need help with the spells and levels involved with the bard class

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, experience-points, bard, character-levels

I'm a little bit confused at the way d20pfrsd sets up their website, and as such, i am not sure how many spells the bard can learn at each level, nor am i certain on how much experience the bard requires to level up. can somebody help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Can you give us some more detail on *what* is confusing you? As-is, this is a pretty difficult question to answer, at least without just rewriting the book/SRD (which we aren’t going to do; that’s not what we are here for). So you can help us help you by giving us more direction into what you need help with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Spells Learned Per Level

> The bard’s selection of spells is extremely limited. A bard begins play knowing four 0-level spells and two 1st-level spells of the bard’s choice. At each new bard level, he gains one or more new spells, as indicated on **Table: Bard Spells Known**.

To the right of [this section of text](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/#TOC-Spells), you will find a table that has listed:

```
Level | 0th | 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 4th | 5th | 6th  
   1  |  4  |  2  |  —  |  —  |  —  |  —  |  —  
   2  |  5  |  3  |  —  |  —  |  —  |  —  |  —
```

And so on. This indicates the *total* number of known spells for the relevant level. If you want to know how many you've earned by levelling up, you can check the differences between your new level and your old level. (*For example, with the above, you've learned 1 new 0th- and 1st-level spell respectively.*)

---

### Experience Required to Level Up

This is, *entirely*, down to the DM, and isn't something that will be influenced by your character class. You can read up on the [*Character Advancement* rules here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/#Advancing_Your_Character), which will likewise indicate a chart with the rules-as-written *(commonly referred to as RAW)* experience points required to attain each new level.

It is worth noting that in *Pathfinder*, characters earn experience points to progress their *Character Level*, and take no penalty to the amount of experience points earned or needed to level up when multi-classing. (Your *Class Level* as referenced in many abilities will refer to how many of your *Character Levels* you've assigned to that particular class.)

*(I would take those with a pinch of salt, though, as from experience most DMs will use a customised experience and levelling system instead of what is presented there.)*

Comment: Particularly since the querent seems to be quite new to D&D/RPGs, might be worth expanding “RAW” here.

Comment: thanks whoever you are who answered, i thought the table was talking about how many i can use per day, which brings up another question, if what you said is the case, how many spells can i use per day

Comment: If you have a look at [the top of the entry for Bard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard), and specifically at _Table: Bard_, on the right-hand side is a set of columns labelled 1st through 6th. The number beneath them are your "Base spells per day" for spells of those levels. You then add to that any bonus determined by [your spell casting ability score.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Abilities-and-Spellcasters) (Keep in mind that you don't get access to spells of a certain level until your base spells per day allows it, even with high stats!)